# Does editing an item in an arraylist count as modifying the list?

Tags: java, arraylist, concurrentmodification

In an ArrayList, if I add/remove items, then this is considered 'modifying' the list. Hence, if i try to iterate over the list while simultaneously trying to add/remove items, i get `ConcurrentModificationException` (unless i use a listIterator).

My question is, if I do an operation like : list.get(index).setValue("newValue"), is it still considered modifying the list?

Comment: Just a side note, You could avoid a `ConcurrentModificationException` by using a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Editing an item in a List is not "modifying the List": The *item* is modified, not the *List*. The List will be unaware of any changes to the items.

Only changes to the item *references* held *by* the List is a modification to the *List*, ie insertions and selections to/from the List.

Comment: this might be true, but I think it's in contradiction with the `equals` implementation of `ArrayList`, which checks element equality with `equals` instead of `==`

Answer (score 3):

Only changes to the list contents (what objects are in the list) will count as a list modification. Changes to the internal state of the objects in the list will not change the list modification counter.

In pathological cases, I suppose, changing the internal state of a list element might indirectly trigger a change to the list itself as a side effect. My first paragraph assumes that nothing like that is going on.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternative answer based on the `equals` implementation of `ArrayList`, which checks the elements by their `equals` method. So, let's consider two lists with non-immutable (mutable) elements (another `ArrayList`) `list1` and `list2`

```
    List<String> mutableElement1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<List<String>> list1 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    list1.add(mutableElement1);

    List<String> mutableElement2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<List<String>> list2 = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    list2.add(mutableElement2);
```

At this point they contain the same elements in the same order, so

```
    assertEquals(list1, list2);
```

passes. Then, I change the element of the first list:

```
    mutableElement1.add("element");
```

then

```
    assertEquals(list1, list2);
```

fails.

According to this, modifying an element of a list modifies the list, too.

Comment: Thanks. But i was asking from the POV of concurrentmodificationexception